# Evaluate $\iint_{S} z^2\, dS$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate $\iint_{S} z^2\, dS$, where $S$ is the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$. Do not use parametrization.

So $$z = \pm \sqrt{4 - x^2 - y^2}$$

$$\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{-x}{\sqrt{4-x^2 -y^2}}$$

$$\frac{dz}{dy} = \frac{-y}{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}$$

thus $$\iint_{S} z^2\, dS = \iint_R (4-x^2-y^2) \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{-x}{\sqrt{4-x^2 -y^2}} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{-y}{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}\right)^2}\,dA$$

$$\iint_R (4-x^2 - y^2) \sqrt{\frac{4}{4-x^2 - y^2}}\,dA = 2 \iint_R (4-x^2-y^2)^{1/2} dA$$

$$2 \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2} \sqrt{4-r^2} r \,dr d \theta = \frac{32 \pi}{3}$$

correct?

Comment: Is it just $1/3$ of integral of $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ over $S$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By rotational symmetry,
$$
I=\iint_S z^2\ dS=\iint_S x^2\ dS=\iint_S y^2\ dS.
$$ So
$$
3I=\iint_S (x^2+y^2+z^2)\ dS=4\iint_S dS=4\cdot 4\pi \cdot 2^2=64\pi
$$ and $I=\frac{64\pi}3$.

Comment: would that be enough for the entire answer?

Comment: Or you can use spherical coordinate $x=2\sin\theta\cos\phi, y=2\sin\theta\sin\phi, z=2\cos\theta$ and $$I=16\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \cos^2\theta \sin\theta d\theta d\phi=32\pi [-\cos^3\theta/3]^{\pi}_0=\frac{64\pi}3.$$

Comment: I'm confused how you go from $$\iint_S (x^2+y^2+z^2)\ dS=4\iint_S dS=4\cdot 4\pi \cdot 2^2=64\pi$$. Can you explain pls

Comment: First, pull out $ x^2+y^2+z^4=4$. We are left with $\iint_S dS=\text{surface area of }S=4\pi r^2|_{r=2}=16\pi$. Finally we have $4\times 16\pi =64 \pi$. Does this make it clear?